# How to exclude webstorm files from search results

Tags: webstorm

I have set up a custom scope in webstorm, and am trying to use it to limit search results by excluding third party libraries and such when doing 'Find in Path'.  However, even though my custom scope is based on my project, I still get results in my search from outside my project.  In particular, I get results from webstorm libraries and plugins:

[image]

I am using Webstorm 10.0.4

How do I filter those results out of my search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue, [IDEA-139723](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139723), please follow this ticket for updates.
To get rid of the issue, I'd suggest using 'include' filters in scope instead of 'exclude' filters - i.e. instead of excluding certain folders, just include everything you'd like being included